# PgPool fails to auth in master_slave mode

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

We have two PostgreSQL servers running in master-slave streaming replication mode, behind pgpool.

When we activate `master_slave` mode in `pgpool.conf`, we get following error:

```
do_md5 failed in slot 1
```

When we add a host with the `md5` method in `pool_hba.conf`, we're getting this error:

```
md5 token is invalid
```

Without `master_slave` mode, `pgpool` connects successfully. Where to dig?

Answer (score 1):

Here are steps wich helped me:

1. You need to check `pgpool.conf` for `enable_pool_hba = on`.
2. Here is a table with description of errors on `pg_hba.conf` and `pool_hba.conf`:
   [FAQ](http://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/FAQ#I_created_pool_hba.conf_and_pool_passwd_to_enable_md5_authentication_through_pgpool-II_but_it_does_not_work._Why.3F)
3. Also check md5 hash for `pool_passwd`, I got it from database using query:

   `select passwd from pg_shadow where usename = 'username';`

Answer (score 0):

Solution, in 2 words: `install latest pgpool2 from sources`

Step by step solution:

1. Make sure that you have pgpool2 with version 3+
2. Create pool_passwd with pg_md5 command
3. Make sure, that you have md5 in pool_hba.conf. If you have pgpool2 from deb - it will not support md5 token in pool_hba.conf